# xcode PBXCp Error

Tags: xcode, image

My Xcode project is really starting to irk me.
I wrote a program that involved multiple png images.  At a random point, it said that frown.png had no such file or directory so I renamed every instance of it to frown2.png and i still got the same error still saying frown.png even though there was no instance of it.
I then took all of my code and images and created a new project.  For a while it worked, but when i tried adding a second view (doubt that caused it), i started getting the same error again still with frown.png.
What should i do?
(P.S. i am very inexperienced in xcode so please keep answers clear and concise.  Thanks)

Comment: Care to share some important information with us? Like what version of Xcode are you using? How are you trying to access these files? Show some of your code? there are too many answers to the problem you listed above. Help us help you.

Comment: Update the screenshot of the error message on your xcode.